# How to prevent to trigger action after clicking on nested child element with clickToggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have menu with structure like this:

```
  <li class="sub-menu ">
  <div class="menu-item"> Nasze wsparcie </div>
  <div class="menu-header "> Nasze wsparcie </div>
  <ul>
  <li> 
    <a class="menu-link" href="http://www.velux.pl/dla-klienta/serwis" 
    target="_blank">Obsługa posprzedażowa</a> 
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a class="menu-link" href="http://www.velux.pl/dla-klienta/zanim-kupisz" 
    target="_blank">Obsługa przedsprzedażowa</a> 
  </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
```

And I want to that clicking  on child element (a) not trigger action which should be triggered after clicking only on parent element (li). I've read other threads on this topic and I tried to use: event.stopPropagation();
But I've received error : e is not defined. When I've tried to do. I don't know maybe I did it wrong place. Please, help me.
My JQuery code is:

```
            jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function(a,b) {
                function cb(){ [b,a][this._tog^=1].call(this); }
                return this.on("click", cb);
            }

            /**************************/



            $(".sub-menu").clickToggle(function() {   

                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('.menu-item').animate({'left':'-100%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
                $(this).find('.menu-header').animate({'right':'4%'}, 'slow', 'linear');

                /*$('.menu-item').addClass('is-hidden');*/
                $(this).find('.menu-header').attr('style', 'display: block !important');
                $('.service').animate({'left':'-100%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
                console.log("przed - 1");
                $(this).find('li').addClass('li-active');
                console.log("po - 1");
                /*$('.sub-menu ul').animate({'right':'0%'}, 'slow', 'linear');*/
                $(this).children('ul').css('display' , 'block');
                $(this).children('ul').animate({'right':'0%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
                $(this).find('a').css('display' , 'block');



            }, function() {

                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $('.menu-item').animate({'left':'4%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
                $(this).find('.menu-header').animate({'right':'-100%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
                $(this).find('.menu-header').attr('style', 'display: none !important');
                $('.service').animate({'left':'0%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
                console.log("przed - 2");
                $(this).find('li').removeClass('li-active');
                console.log("po - 2");
                /*$('.sub-menu ul').animate({'right':'-100%'}, 'slow', 'linear');*/
                $(this).children('ul').css('display' , 'none');
                $(this).children('ul').animate({'right':'-100%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
                $(this).find('a').css('display' , 'none');

                /*$('.menu-item').removeClass('is-hidden');*/

            });
        }
```

So I've prepared fiddle to show problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/xot7va4z/

Comment: Put your working snippet with error

Comment: I guess you used stopPropagation() in a wrong way. If you pass "e" as an argument, you should also call e.stopPropagation() instead of event.stopPropagation().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the [event target attribute](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) in order to decide if toggle the class. But, you need the event object in your functions. This can be done passing the event argument to the functions in this line ([Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)):

```
[b,a][this._tog^=1].call(this);
```

Change it to:

```
[b,a][this._tog^=1].call(this, e);
```

Now, you have the event in both a and b functions.

An example:

```js
jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function(a,b) {
    function cb(e){ [b,a][this._tog^=1].call(this, e); }
    return this.on("click", cb);
}

/**************************/


$(".sub-menu").clickToggle(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('active');


}, function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).removeClass('active');

});
```

```css
.active{
    background-color:red;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
.sub-menu{
    border:1px solid black;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
    <li class="sub-menu ">Parent
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="menu-link" href="http://www.velux.pl/dla-klienta/serwis"
                   target="_blank">Obsługa posprzedażowa</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="menu-link" href="http://www.velux.pl/dla-klienta/zanim-kupisz"
                   target="_blank">Child element</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer and this snippet but it's not exactly what I want because I would like to clicking on anchor caused opening a new tab but the rest of action like animations and other was disabled when I clicking on anchor but was triggered only when I click on li element. I've prepeared snippet to show it in better way.

Comment: Thank you very much but else not, maybe I have a problem with explaining it, so I've link to prepared fiddle in my post above and :
1) Now, it works in this way, that when I click: li - background change to red and it's ok. When I click - a, I am moved to new tab and it's ok. But ...
When I return from new tab to my page with menu, background is red and it's not ok. Because I want to there was no changes in background, only moving to new tab when I click anchor.

Comment: thanks, if you're not sure what is my problem, please give me know, I would be very grateful for help

Comment: @Tergo  Answer updated and the same for [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xot7va4z/2/). Let me know

Comment: Yes. :) It works fine. Now it's exactly what I wanted to do.  gaetanoM, you're great and you save my life today, really...